# How can I use bash commands in an interactive environment?

Tags: linux, bash

As the questions says, I have problems using several commands in an interactive environment. For example, I'm compiling the kernel, and I type the following commands:

```
bash << fin
make nconfig   # this is an interactive command
xdotool key F9  # this simulate a keystroke
xdotool key Return # this simulate a keystroke
xdotool key Return # this simulate a keystroke
fin
```

It works, but I have the restlessness of why i always get this in the stderror:

```
bash: line 3: 0: command not found
```

(where line 3 = `bash << fin`)

Comment: is the posted code enough to reproduce the problem?

Comment: sorry, it doesnt , the full code is :                                                                           #!/bin/bash  echo "some comment  here"                                                                                  bash << fin
make nconfig   # this is an interactive command
xdotool key F9  # this simulate a keystroke
xdotool key Return # this simulate a keystroke
xdotool key Return # this simulate a keystroke
fin                                                                                                                        echo "some others comments here"

Comment: That code is not enough to reproduce the problem either.  The error message says that `bash` could not find a command named `0`.  Where, __in your real code__, do you have a misplaced zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error says that your current shell can not find command `bash`

```
bash: line 3: 0: command not found
```

So either use a different shell, or setup your paths correctly that it resolves to `/bin/bash` instead of just `bash`. This could solve it for you then:

```
/bin/bash << fin
make nconfig   # this is an interactive command
xdotool key F9  # this simulate a keystroke
xdotool key Return # this simulate a keystroke
xdotool key Return # this simulate a keystroke
fin
```

Comment: But if that's the case, then you've surely seen an error message about `fin`.